# How can I add a navigation controller to my own container view controller in iOS5?

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, splitcontainer

I'm trying to create a container view controller (see screenshot) and I would like to add a navigation controller at the right, but I'm having some problems. Can you help me?

When I add this code in my parent controller (viewDidLoad), I see the view with other position/size, I guess because I can't access navigation controller container view.

Tried:

```
[self addChildViewController:_detailNavigationController];
_detailNavigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(256, 49, 768, 651);
[self.view addSubview:_detailNavigationController.view];
```

And also this, but only works with the first view, evidently.

```
[self addChildViewController:_detailNavigationController];
_detailNavigationController.topViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(256, 49, 768, 651);
[self.view addSubview:_detailNavigationController..topViewController.view];
```

Tried a hack to get navigation controller container view, but doesn't work, I see nothing on the screen and using the debugger I realized view is nil. Apart from that, likely Apple don't like this.

```
[self addChildViewController:_detailNavigationController];
UIView *view = [_detailNavigationController valueForKey:@"_containerView"];
view.frame = CGRectMake(256, 49, 768, 651);
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Am I missing something?
Do you know how I can add a navigation controller inside my own customized container view controller?
Thanks in advance!

Screenshot:
http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/2464/screennjz.png

Answer (score 1):

I have custom classes MasterViewController and DetailedViewController are subclasses of UITableViewController. NavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController and SplitViewController is a subclass of UISplitViewController.

As you can see it works but I am having a problem when I pop a view from the navigation controller. If you find out how to fix this let me know.

[image]

```
    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];

    NavigationController *masterNav = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:master];

    DetailedViewController *detailed = [[DetailedViewController alloc] init];

    NavigationController *detailedNav = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailed];

    myVC = [[SplitViewController alloc] init];

    [myVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNav, detailedNav, nil]];
```

Comment: The problem I was having was because not all of my VC were landscape so it flipped out.